# Active hosts in ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'd like to write simple software in .NET which will work with ActiveDirectory. I'd like to list all hosts which are active or users which are logged in domain. Is there any easy way to do that in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Google search would help :)

You can use `System.DirectoryServices` for that.

Here is a nice article about all the possibilities:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

Comment: That link doesn't show anything about actve systems or currently logged on users...

Answer (score 0):

"Active" is a pretty subjective term. What defines active to you?

You probably want to look at the `lastLogonTimeStamp` attribute as an approximation of activity, I'd guess, though.

Comment: Right, i wasn't precise. I'm trying to get which hosts/machines are turned on and list users logged on that machines. I'd like to get table |Host|Username|Logged in since|
Should i try do it in .NET or maybe PowerShell could help me? I'm not familiar with PS and I'm looking for easiest solution, but maybe PowerShell has something almost out of the box. So, C# or PowerShell? what would be easier?

Comment: The data you're asking for isn't ordinarily stored in Active Directory. You'd need to scrape the event log of each domain controller to collect and correlate it. If you have Vista/2008+ clients and domain controllers, you could enable the Interactive Logon Statistics functionality - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749292(WS.10).aspx. It is turned off by default, though given the impact it has on AD. Here's another link: http://jeftek.com/218/display-previous-logon-information-for-vista-users/